# Combo box bound to a field required to show All before a selection is made on the Combo box

Tags: c#

I have created a Combo box bound to "Clinics" field of a table. I wanted to show "All" on the first line of the Combo box list to show all activities of the clinics by default in a table. When a specific clinic is selected it shows the activities of the selected clinic.
My script looks like this:

[My Code looks like this]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myconn"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        string sqlquery = "select * from [dbo].[EC_HARS_DQ]";
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
        sqlconn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sdr = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sdr.Fill(dt);
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "clinic";
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        sqlconn.Close();


    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myconn"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        string sqlquery = "select * from [dbo].[EC_HARS_DQ] where clinic='"+comboBox1.Text.ToString()+"'";
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
        sqlconn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sdr = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sdr.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        sqlconn.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Insert "All" into the first row of whatever collection holds your data in the C# side

Comment: Your code looks like what? Don't post a picture- it's harder work for you and less useful for us than selecting the code, pressing Ctrl-C, editing your question and pressing Ctrl-V

Answer (score 0):

First off, refrain from `SELECT *`, instead select only needed columns.

You can add `All` using a UNION.

In this example, table name is Categories with the intent to provide the primary key for use after a selection is made and description to display.

```
SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM dbo.Categories;
```

Now using a SELECT with 0 in this case to represent an identifier and 'All` to display in the ComboBox then union for all rows in the table.

```
SELECT 0 AS CategoryID, 'All' AS CategoryName 
UNION ALL SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM dbo.Categories;
```

[image]

In code you can read the data into a DataTable, set [DisplayMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), in this case to CategoryName and [ValueMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to CategoryID.

When a selection is made check [SelectedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), if 0 `All` is the selection, else an existing primary key would be used for your business logic.